# Error while using spring-cloud-bus with aws kinesis stream binder

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, amazon-kinesis

I want to use the `actuator/bus-refresh` for signaling my config change across my containers and for that I use:

```
spring.cloud.bus.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=bus-refresh
```

and when I enable the spring-bus, I am getting an error like

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make final void java.lang.Throwable.setCause(java.lang.Throwable) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @2f112965
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil.checkAndFixAccess(ClassUtil.java:987)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMember.fixAccess(AnnotatedMember.java:139)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.fixAccess(MethodProperty.java:95)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBuilder._fixAccess(BeanDeserializerBuilder.java:522)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBuilder.build(BeanDeserializerBuilder.java:373)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.buildThrowableDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:456)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:112)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:414)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:349)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:264)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:591)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:4733)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:4569)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2798)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.treeToValue(ObjectMapper.java:3261)
    at com.amazonaws.transform.JsonErrorUnmarshaller.unmarshall(JsonErrorUnmarshaller.java:61)
    at com.amazonaws.http.JsonErrorResponseHandler.doLegacyUnmarshall(JsonErrorResponseHandler.java:185)
    at com.amazonaws.http.JsonErrorResponseHandler.unmarshallException(JsonErrorResponseHandler.java:147)
    at com.amazonaws.http.JsonErrorResponseHandler.createException(JsonErrorResponseHandler.java:131)
    at com.amazonaws.http.JsonErrorResponseHandler.handle(JsonErrorResponseHandler.java:94)
    at com.amazonaws.http.JsonErrorResponseHandler.handle(JsonErrorResponseHandler.java:40)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AwsErrorResponseHandler.handleAse(AwsErrorResponseHandler.java:58)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AwsErrorResponseHandler.handle(AwsErrorResponseHandler.java:45)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AwsErrorResponseHandler.handle(AwsErrorResponseHandler.java:27)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1801)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1403)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1372)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.doInvoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:6214)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:6181)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.executeDescribeTable(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:2247)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.describeTable(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:2211)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Table.describe(Table.java:137)
    at org.springframework.integration.aws.metadata.DynamoDbMetadataStore.isTableAvailable(DynamoDbMetadataStore.java:219)
    at org.springframework.integration.aws.metadata.DynamoDbMetadataStore.afterPropertiesSet(DynamoDbMetadataStore.java:153)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.initializeBinderContextSimple(DefaultBinderFactory.java:471)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinderInstance(DefaultBinderFactory.java:265)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.doGetBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:223)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:151)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.getBinder(BindingService.java:389)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindConsumer(BindingService.java:106)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindableProxyFactory.createAndBindInputs(AbstractBindableProxyFactory.java:118)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.InputBindingLifecycle.doStartWithBindable(InputBindingLifecycle.java:58)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:647)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindingLifecycle.start(AbstractBindingLifecycle.java:57)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.InputBindingLifecycle.start(InputBindingLifecycle.java:34)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:453)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:343)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1370)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1359)
```

> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to
> start bean 'inputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'kinesisBinderHealthIndicator' defined
> in
> org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.config.KinesisBinderConfiguration$KinesisBinderHealthIndicatorConfiguration:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
> 'kinesisBinderHealthIndicator' parameter 0; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>
> Error creating bean with name 'kinesisMessageChannelBinder' defined
> in
> org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.config.KinesisBinderConfiguration:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
> 'kinesisMessageChannelBinder' parameter 3; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'kinesisCheckpointStore' defined in
> org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.config.KinesisBinderConfiguration:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: Unable to unmarshall exception
> response with the unmarshallers provided (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2;
> Status Code: 400; Error Code: UnrecognizedClientException; Request ID:
> 3KJ3G5IL9THKIFUM91DNAV6AI3VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG; Proxy: null)

What am I missing here ? Why does it require a dynamo db?

And if I don't enable the spring-cloud-bus, the `actuator/bus-refresh` is not getting exposed even if I provide

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=bus-refresh
```

Answer (score 1):

That's true: the Kinesis Binder requires DynamoDb and CloudWatch for KCL for offset management. You may simply disable that with `SimpleMessageStore` bean to replace default DynamoDb one.